# How to query array in muliti-conditions C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have an array called UsedCars[10,5]

And it's data looks like

```
Car Brand       Car Color   Quantity
Alfa Romeo         Red         5
Dodge              Blue        1
Ferrari            Yellow      12
Dodge              Blue        3
Alfa Romeo         Red         5
Dodge              Red         18
```

I want get the summation of each car brand which is in the same color
So result must be

```
Alfa Romeo         Red         10
Dodge              Blue        4
Ferrari            Yellow      12
Dodge              Red         18
```

My idea is adding all of those data from the UsedCars array into a Datatable then i make a loop on all rows in the DataTable to make a query (select) on each row and compare it's data to sum the quantity And put them all again the Datatable

Any short way to decrease using of resources and run time?

Comment: Do include the actual declaration of your array! - You may want to look into LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ. Example from here : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Aggregate-Operators-c51b3869

```
List<Product> products = GetProductList(); 

var categories = 
    from p in products 
    group p by p.Category into g 
    select new { Category = g.Key, TotalUnitsInStock = g.Sum(p => p.UnitsInStock) };
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a good LINQ implementation for you, but it seems very hard to combine multi-dimensional arrays (`object[,]`) with LINQ, because the provided enumerator iterates over every single "cell" of the array.

So I guess a better approach is to add the quantities in a dictionary like this:

```
Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>> usedCars = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, int>>();
for(int i=0; i<UsedCars.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    string brand = UsedCars[i, 0].ToString();
    string color = UsedCars[i, 1].ToString();
    int quantity = (int)UsedCars[i,2];

    if (!usedCars.ContainsKey(brand))
        usedCars.Add(brand, new Dictionary<string, int>());

    if (usedCars[brand].ContainsKey(color))
        usedCars[brand][color] += quantity;
    else
        usedCars[brand][color] = quantity;
}
```

I assume that the brand, color and quantitiy you showed us are the first three "cells" per "row" in your `object[10,5]` array.

---

The resulting dictionary can be used like this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Quantity of yellow ferraris: {usedCars["Ferrari"]["Yellow"]}");
```